# Optimal solution to non-linear program

Tags: solution-verification, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Find an optimal solution to the following problem:

$$\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2}(x_i-1)^2$$
$$\text{s.t. } x\ge0 \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=1.$$

Comment: Can you elaborate your confusion and why you dismissed a solution where the non negativity constraints are active?

Comment: @copper.hat Yeah, so here's why I'm confused. I notice that if I can somehow make the assumption that $x_i>0$, then I can conclude $\lambda_i = 0$ which arrives me at the optimal solution without any effort. I'm curious if there is some justification in dismissing that solution as non-optimal, or if it just shouldn't have been done.

Comment: You would need to show that by increasing a zero $x_i$ (and reducing the others in some way to maintain the constraint) then the cost can be decreased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let $e=(1,...,1)$ the the problem becomes
$\min_{e^T x = 1, x \ge 0 } { 1\over 2} \|x-e\|^2$ which we can see is
projecting the point $e$ onto the simplex.

One nice characteristic of this problem is that it is convex, and first order conditions are necessary and sufficient.

One approach is to solve a more relaxed problem and if this is a solution then it solves the more constrained problem.

Solving $\min_{e^T x = 1 } { 1\over 2} \|x-e\|^2$ gives
$(x-e) + \lambda e = 0$, or $x=(1-\lambda) e$ and from the
constraint we have $e^T x = 1 = (1-\lambda) e^T e  = n (1-\lambda)$ and so
$(1-\lambda) = {1 \over n}$ which gives
$x = {1 \over n} e$. Since $x>0$ this solves the original problem.

Comment: That's a really cool way of reframing the problem! How did you arrive at $(x-e)+\lambda e = 0$?

Comment: This is just the equation you have (except I used $\lambda$ instead of your $\mu$ and there are no multipliers for the inequality constraints) in vector form.

Comment: Thank you! This cleared my confusion :)

Comment: +1 for a different solution (and perspective), but I think what OP has done is good for learning, because it's a routine. If one looks for simpler solutions then nothing beats $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$.

Answer (score 1):

First, to answer your question regarding $\lambda_i = 0 \ \forall i$, I would suggest a simpler argument, as follows.

Assume that $\lambda_i > 0$ for some $i$, then
$$x_i=0\implies\mu-1=-\lambda_1< 0\implies x_j-\lambda_j<0\forall j \implies \lambda_j > 0\ \forall j \implies x_j=0\ \forall j,$$
which is of course not feasible.

Second, there's a simple and elementary proof for the problem in the question. Notice that $(x_i-1/n)^2 \ge 0$, we have that $x_i^2 \ge ax_i+b$ for some $a,b$. Sum up this inequality for all $i$ we see that the objective function in the equation is no smaller than a constant, with equality iff $x_i=1/n\ \forall i$.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for, thank you :)

Comment: @gaussianwolf You should upvote answers that you find useful, including this one and cooper.hat's one that you accepted.

Comment: I have! They are recorded but not publicly displayed until I have enough rep (which I'll hopefully have soon).

Comment: @gaussianwolf I see. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I didn’t notice that you are a new member. Good luck with your studies!

Comment: @gaussianwolf I’ve upvoted your questions ;)

Comment: And now I can upvote everyone's answers! Thanks!

Comment: @gaussianwolf Nice. Congrats ;)